# Select all nodes matching a condition, with the first record of a n-n relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have 3 type of nodes: Articles, Shares, Boards.

An article can be shared in multiple boards, so there's an 1-n relation between a Share and an Article, and an 1-n between a Share and a Board.

```
(article:`Article`)<-[:shared_article]-(share:`Share`)-[:shared_in]->(board:`Board`)
```

I want to select an `Article`, loading also the **first** `Board` in which it was shared (A share has a creation date attribute)

How can I build this query in cypher?

I tried this:

```
MATCH (article:`Article`)<-[:shared_article]-(share:`Share`)-[:shared_in]->(board:`Board`)
WHERE article.created_at > ?
RETURN DISTINCT(article), board
ORDER BY board.created_at DESC
```

But it's not working.

I also tried this:

```
MATCH (article:`Article`)<-[:shared_article]-(share:`Share`)-[:shared_in]->(board:`Board`)
WHERE article.created_at > ?
WITH article, board
ORDER BY board.created_at DESC
RETURN article, head(collect(board))
```

And it's working, but... I think it's quite inefficient, since I select all nodes, than I takes the first.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Please define "it's not working" by providing expected result and what you got.

Comment: It's not working means: It's not returning distinct articles with exactly one desk per article, since there are repetitions (of articles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query might work for you. It sorts the distinct `article`/`board` pairs by `board.created_at` (in *ascending* order, since you wanted the *first* board), aggregates all the `board`s for each `article`, and returns each `article` and its first `board`. I assume that a `time` parameter is provided.

```
MATCH (article:Article)<-[:shared_article]-(share:Share)-[:shared_in]->(board:Board)
WHERE article.created_at > {time}
WITH DISTINCT article, board
ORDER BY board.created_at 
WITH article, COLLECT(board) AS boards
RETURN article, boards[0] AS first_board;
```

I assume that `time` is provided as a [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html).